# How to parse JsonPrimitive

Tags: json, gson

I have the following json which i need to parse:

```
{
 "resource1": {
  "fare": 7511,
  "typeoftravel": "domestic",
  "vertical": "flight",
  "extra": "[{'duration': u'3h 0m', 'arrtime': u'2015-05-05t1930', 'nostops': 0, 'deptime': u'2015-05-05t1630', 'flightno': u'6E478'}]",
  "roundtrip": "O",
  "destination": "BLR",
  "returndate": 0,
  "lastupdated": "2015-03-29T10:40:12",
  "source": "IXC",
  "carrier": "IndiGo",
  "date": 20150505,
  "class": "E"
 },
 "resource2": {
  "fare": 6320,
  "typeoftravel": "domestic",
  "vertical": "flight",
  "extra": "[{'duration': u'4h 25m', 'arrtime': u'2015-05-06t2210', 'nostops': 0, 'deptime': u'2015-05-06t1745', 'flightno': u'9W7076'}]",
  "roundtrip": "O",
  "destination": "BLR",
  "returndate": 0,
  "lastupdated": "2015-03-29T17:08:09",
  "source": "IXC",
  "carrier": "Jet Airways",
  "date": 20150506,
  "class": "E"
 }
}
```

I am not able to determine what kind of field "extra" is. It's not a jsonObject or jsonArray. I am able to cast it to jsonPrimitive but now how do i parse this. I am using Gson for parsing.

Comment: Just see and try my solution, I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the following classes:

**Resources:**

```
public class Resources {

    Resource resource1;
    Resource resource2;
}
```

**Resource:**

```
import java.util.List;

public class Resource {

    int fare;
    String typeoftravel;
    String vertical;
    String roundtrip;
    String destination;
    int returndate;
    String lastupdated;
    String source;
    String carrier;
    long date;
    String clazz;
    List<Extra> extra;
}
```

**Extra:**

```
public class Extra {

    String duration;
    String arrtime;
    int nostops;
    String deptime;
    String flightno;
}
```

One possible solution, is to register new `JsonSerializer` to your `Gson` object, which will

1. Copy all normal fields, except `extra`
2. Extract `extra` as String
3. Parse extracted `extra` again to remove the quotes
4. Then deserialize it as List using `TypeToken`

See below code for explanation

**ResourceDeserializer**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;


public class ResourceDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Resource> {

    @Override
    public Resource deserialize(JsonElement value, Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        final JsonObject resourceJson = value.getAsJsonObject();

        final Resource resource = new Resource();
        resource.fare = resourceJson.get("fare").getAsInt();
        resource.typeoftravel = resourceJson.get("typeoftravel").getAsString();
        resource.vertical = resourceJson.get("vertical").getAsString();
        resource.roundtrip = resourceJson.get("roundtrip").getAsString();
        resource.destination = resourceJson.get("destination").getAsString();
        resource.returndate = resourceJson.get("returndate").getAsInt();
        resource.lastupdated = resourceJson.get("lastupdated").getAsString();
        resource.source = resourceJson.get("source").getAsString();
        resource.carrier = resourceJson.get("carrier").getAsString();
        resource.date = resourceJson.get("date").getAsLong();
        resource.clazz = resourceJson.get("class").getAsString();

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Extra>>(){}.getType();

        String extraStr = resourceJson.get("extra").getAsString();

        extraStr = extraStr.replaceAll("u?(\'[^\']+\')", "$1");

        JsonElement extraList = new JsonParser().parse(extraStr);

        resource.extra = context.deserialize(extraList, listType);

        return resource;
    }

}
```

Registering the above deserializer

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Resource.class, new ResourceDeserializer())
        .create();
```

> Note that, I renamed the attribute `class` to `clazz`, because `class`
>   is a reserved word!

Comment: Hi, with your code, it gets stuck in the "fromJson" method in Gson.java in this line "TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = getAdapter(typeToken);"

Comment: I think, the json i am getting from the API is wrong, Json doesn't support single quotes but for extra there are single quotes. Any idea how to get around that ?

Comment: So simple, just update the RegExp to catch the single quotes `extraStr = extraStr.replaceAll("u?(\'[^\']+\')", "$1");`, because the problem comes from the `u` modifier